# Is there any way select by ordinal number in Presto?

Tags: presto, trino

From the doc, we can group by ordinal in Presto:

```
SELECT count(*), nationkey FROM customer GROUP BY 2;

SELECT count(*), nationkey FROM customer GROUP BY nationkey;
```

My question, is there any way to select by ordinal number? I just want something like:

```
SELECT customer.1, customer.2 FROM customer;
```

Comment: Not possible AFAIK...you could do this using dynamic SQL, assuming Presto support it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What is dynamic SQL? Could you please give more information about that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible.

As a workaround, you can generate such a query using `information_schema` (it's not documented today, see https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/5345). [`format()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) function can be useful. However you accomplish this, you need to re-submit generated SQL yourself.